# Determine if Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.ParameterInfo is a Variable?

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to list Parameters from a SSISDB and filter out Variables. How can I determine if a Package parameter is a Variable?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a project to the server, you use views, stored procedures, and the SQL Server Management Studio UI to manage project and package parameters.

[catalog.object_parameters (SSISDB Database) (view)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878140.aspx) - Displays the parameters and properties for all packages and projects in the Integration Services catalog, including the design default and server default values.

Also you can use [this script](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/SSISDB.catalog.get_any_parameter_values.sql) to retrieve a list of parameters belonging to project.

[SSIS Environments And Parameter Values](http://copper-blue.co.uk/2012/05/02/ssis-environments-and-parameter-values/)